# Menu send signal to main view in order to segue

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

[image]

I have the main view from where I want to segue to other view controllers in order have the "Back button" to "Main View" in the second view controllers.

In my menu (SWRevealViewController) (1), I want to send a signal to "Main view" to do the segue.

I have tried different ways like:

- Call a function in "Main View".
- Use "didSet" and "willSet" to change a var and do the segue.
- ...

But I always obtains this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Recipe.CategoriesViewController: 0x10be61910>) has no segue with identifier 'showLogin''
```

I don't want to do segue directly from (1) to (2) because I need to use the "Main view" like a parent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't comment on the question because of my low reputation, hence mentioning it as an answer.

For the kind of behavior, you're looking for why don't you use `UIPageViewController`.

So you can have the "Main View" as the parent view controller and the others as the child controllers.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a UICollectionView and methods like collectionView.reloadData() make me a fatal error if I use UIPageViewController